# How can I add multiple dictionaries to a key inside a main dictionary? Example is given below

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I input products with 'prod_id' and 'prod_name' as keys in respective category_id. When a user requests for category_id_2 he should be able to add 'prod_id' and 'prod_name' in that particular category.

```
 { 
            {
                'category_id_1':{'prod_id': 'f1a1', 'prod_name': 'apple'},
                                {'prod_id': 'f1a2', 'prod_name': 'banana'},
                                {'prod_id': 'f1a2', 'prod_name': 'banana'}
            }, 
        
            {
                'category_id_2':{'prod_id': 'v1b1', 'prod_name': 'bottle gourd'},
                                {'prod_id': 'v1c1', 'prod_name': 'cauli flower'}
            },
        }
```

Below is the code of the following!

```
import sys

inventory = []
final_temp = {}

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp_category_data = {}

    def add_category(self,category_id):
        self.temp_category_data = {category_id:{}}
        print(self.temp_category_data)

    def add_products(self,category_id,prod_id,prod_name):
        self.temp_category_data = {category_id:{}}
        self.temp_category_data[category_id]['prod_id'] = prod_id
        self.temp_category_data[category_id]['prod_name'] = prod_name
        # final_temp.add(self.temp_category_data)
        inventory.append(self.temp_category_data)

x = input("Enter [0] to exit and [1] to continue:\n")
while x != '0':
    if x=='0':
        print("Bye!")
        sys.exit()
    if x=='1':
        y = input("\nEnter \n[1] Add Categories \n\t[1a] Add to existing category \n[2] Add Products\n[3] Search Categories \n[4] Search Products and \n[5] Delete Product\n")
        if y == '1':
            categoryId = input("\nEnter The Category ID: ")
            # categoryName = input("\nEnter The Category Name: ")
            
            inv = Inventory()
            inv.add_category(categoryId)
            print(inventory)
            continue

        if y == '2':
            categoryId = input("\nEnter The Category ID: ")
            prodId = input("\nEnter The Product ID: ")
            prodName = input("\nEnter The Product Name: ")
            
            inv = Inventory()
            inv.add_products(categoryId,prodId,prodName)
            
            print(inventory)
        
        else:
            print("Wrong input Details!!")
            sys.exit()
    x = input("Enter [1] to continue and [0] to exit:\n")
```

Basically i want to implement a inventory management system!

Comment: Please check your `category_id_1` and `category_id_2`. Are those supposed to be list?

Comment: Okay even if i category_id_1 and category_id_2 are considered to be lists then how can i implement the thing asked in my question?

Comment: Your data structure is totally messed up, Dictionary can only contain key with single values. This value can be **SINGLE** string, int, list, or even dict (as you have here `{category_id:{}}`). category_id is the key, and its value is `{}` empty dict. `category_id` is already done with the value. Since it's not a list you cannot append another data to `category_id` as above. To solve this issue, create a list.  `{category_id:[ ]}`. Whenever a new `prod_id` and `prod_name` enters your system: APPEND A DICT to the list.

Comment: In short, try modifying `{category_id:{}}` to `{category_id:[]}`. And the rest of the code repectively.

`inventory[category_id].append({'prod_id': 'f1a2', 'prod_name': 'banana'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can optimize your dictionary to look like this:

```
{'category A':
    {'Product Id A1' : 'Product Name A1', 
     'Product Id A2' : 'Product Name A2'},

 'category B':
    {'Product Id B1' : 'Product Name B1', 
     'Product Id B2' : 'Product Name B2',
     'Product Id B3' : 'Product Name B3'}
}
```

This will allow for you to search for the category and product id quickly.

Example of this would be:

```
{'Fruits': 
    {'Fruit_Id_1': 'Apple', 
     'Fruit_Id_2': 'Banana', 
     'Fruit_Id_3': 'Grapes'},
 'Animals': 
    {'Animal_Id_1': 'Bear',
     'Animal_Id_2': 'Goose'}
}
```

To create , search, and delete the contents in a nested dictionary, you can use the below code:

```
cat_dict = {}
def category(opt):
    while True:
        cname = input ('Enter Category Name : ')
        if cname == '': continue
        if opt == '1' and cname in cat_dict:
            print ('Category already exist. Please re-enter')
        elif opt != '1' and cname not in cat_dict:
            print ('Category does not exist. Please re-enter')
        else:
            return cname

def product(cname,opt):
    while True:
        pid = input ('Enter Product Id : ')
        if pid == '': continue
        elif opt == '1': return pid
        elif opt == '2' and pid in cat_dict[cname]:
            print ('Product Id already exist. Please re-enter')
        elif opt != '2' and pid not in cat_dict[cname]:
            print ('Product Id does not exist. Please re-enter')
        else:
            return pid

        
while x:=input("Enter [0] to exit:\n") != '0':
    while True:
        options= input('''Enter
[1] Add Categories
[2] Add Products
[3] Search Categories
[4] Search Products
[5] Delete Category
[6] Delete Product
> ''') 
        if options not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6'):
            print ('Incorrect Entry. Please re-enter\n')
        else:
            break

    #Valid option has been selected

    #Get Category Name
    cat_name = category(options)

    #Get Product Id
    if options in ('1','2','4','6'):
        prod_id = product(cat_name,options)

    #Get Product Name
    if options in ('1','2'):
        while True:
            prod_name = input ('Enter Product Name : ')
            if prod_name != '': break
    
    #Ready to process options 1 thru 6

    #Option 1: Insert Category, Product Id, and Product Name
    if options == '1':
        cat_dict[cat_name] = {prod_id : prod_name}

    #Option 2: Insert Product Id, and Product Name for given Cateogry
    elif options == '2':
        cat_dict[cat_name].update({prod_id : prod_name})

    #Option 3: print out all Product Id and Product Name for requested Category
    elif options == '3':
        print ('All Products with',cat_name, 'are :', cat_dict[cat_name])

    #Option 4: print out the Product Name for requested Category and Product Id
    elif options == '4':
        print ('Product Name for ',prod_id, 'is :', cat_dict[cat_name][prod_id])

    #Option 5: Delete the requested Category and all Product Ids and Product Names
    elif options == '5':
        confirm_delete = cat_dict.pop(cat_name, None)
        if confirm_delete is not None:
            print ('Category :',cat_name,'successfully deleted')

    #Option 6: Delete the Product Id and Product Name within the given Category
    else:
        confirm_delete = cat_dict[cat_name].pop(prod_id, None)
        if confirm_delete is not None:
            print ('Product Id :', prod_id, 'in category:', cat_name,'successfully deleted')
```

I have tested this and it works properly. Let me know if you find any bugs or areas of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess logically so I'm offering two approaches

in `add_category` change

```
self.temp_category_data = {category_id:{}}
```

to be a list:

```
self.temp_category_data = {category_id:[]}
```

and in `add_products` change the way you add stuff from to be append, because its a list

```
self.temp_category_data[category_id]['prod_id'] = prod_id
self.temp_category_data[category_id]['prod_name'] = prod_name
```

to

```
self.temp_category_data[category_id].append({'prod_id':prod_id, 'prod_name':prod_name})
```

this way you will have a list of dictionaries, but will have to look through it to find any specific one.

Another approach, which will work if "prod_id" are unique per category, is to only change `add_products` like this:

```
self.temp_category_data[category_id][prod_id] = prod_name
```

this will give you a single dictionary which doesnt require you to search through

Comment: Okay but this is the question
Implement inventory management system for shop using list
data structure and oo python.
 Add categories with id
 Add new item in category of goods
 Remove item from category of goods
 Search item by category name /id
 Search item by product name/id

Comment: @HarshKothari use the second approach, it lets you search faster. do you need the ability to search both by product name and id? searching by id is easy because that the key of the dict O(1), by value will require you to iterate over values O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find this helpful.

```
inventory = {}

class Inventory:
    def add_category(self,category_id):
        inventory[category_id] = {}
        print(inventory)

    def add_products(self,category_id,prod_id,prod_name):
        inventory[category_id]['prod_id'] = prod_id
        inventory[category_id]['prod_name'] = prod_name

x = input("Enter [0] to exit and [1] to continue:\n")
while x != '0':
    if x=='0':
        print("Bye!")
        sys.exit()
    if x=='1':
        y = input("\nEnter \n[1] Add Categories \n\t[1a] Add to existing category \n[2] Add Products\n[3] Search Categories \n[4] Search Products and \n[5] Delete Product\n")
        if y == '1':
            categoryId = input("\nEnter The Category ID: ")
            # categoryName = input("\nEnter The Category Name: ")
        
            inv = Inventory()
            inv.add_category(categoryId)
            print(inventory)
            continue

        if y == '2':
            categoryId = input("\nEnter The Category ID: ")
            prodId = input("\nEnter The Product ID: ")
            prodName = input("\nEnter The Product Name: ")
        
            inv = Inventory()
            inv.add_products(categoryId,prodId,prodName)
        
            print(inventory)
    
        else:
            print("Wrong input Details!!")
            sys.exit()
     x = input("Enter [1] to continue and [0] to exit:\n")
```

Output:`{'Food': {'prod_id': 'Meat', 'prod_name': 'Meat'}, 'Fruits': {'prod_id': 'Melon', 'prod_name': 'Melon'}}`

Comment: I am not able to add more than 1 products in category_id. When i add more than 1 products then the previous data is updated. So i don't want that to happen.

Comment: The limitation is with the way the product has been added to the dictionary. You need to use `dict.update(new_dict)` to extend the category dict. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519305/how-can-i-add-multiple-dictionaries-to-a-key-inside-a-main-dictionary-example-i/65521935#65521935) for alternate approach